# Disk of convergence of 3 power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am given 3 power series and I want to find (if possible) the region of the complex plane in which the power series converge at the same time. The power series are

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z+1)^n}{n^a}, \ a \in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[3+(-1)^n]z^n, \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}(z-ei)^n$

For the first one I have $\displaystyle \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \frac{n^a \cdot |z+1|}{(n+1)^a} = |z+1| \cdot \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^a} \longrightarrow |z+1| \implies$ disk of convergence is $D(-1,1)$.

For the third one $\displaystyle \frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|} = \frac{(n+1) \cdot n^n \cdot n!}{(n+1) \cdot (n+1)^n \cdot n!} |z-ei| = |z-ei| \cdot \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n} \longrightarrow \frac{|z-ei|}{e} \implies$ disk of convergence is $D(ei,e)$.

But, I don't know how to approach the second one. I think that because of the $(-1)^n$ the second series will converge only for $z=0 \ (?)$. Also, my approach of the other series is correct? Thanks for any help!